# fdisk partition type shown as empy when type is an UUID

Tags: linux, debian, partition, fdisk, sfdisk

I have two systems with same versions (Debian 11.7, util-linux 2.36.1-8+deb11u1).
Why one system shows partition types as UUIDS and the second doesn't and also doesn't recognize that types showing "Empty" as the type?

Background:
The second one booted through PXE and I'm setting the partitions table as a copy of the first one.
To export from PC1:

> $ sfdisk -d /dev/sda > "table-file.tbl"

> $ cat "table-file.tbl"

Notice types are UUIDS

```
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 250069646
sector-size: 512

# /boot/efi
/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     1048576, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=A454F449-08EA-48E0-BFAD-7D1190CB1DF3
#Main: /
/dev/sda2 : start=     1050624, size=    58593280, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=46A2A596-C2E9-4D3B-9518-7D1496202576
# Extra partition: /extra
/dev/sda3 : start=    59643904, size=   185546752, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=FDF1C229-8C35-4324-989F-4EE98B30503B
# Swap partition
/dev/sda4 : start=   245190656, size=     4878336, type=0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F, uuid=67FE00D9-2F09-4C4C-BD07-7129872D48C0
```

Moved the file to a shared network dir and used it on PC2:

> $ sfdisk /dev/sda < "table-file.tbl" --no-reread; partprove

Now on the new system, fdisk -l reports empty as type:

> fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: TS128GSSD452K-I
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf0c0c704

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1050623   1048576  512M  0 Empty
/dev/sda2         1050624  59643903  58593280 27.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda3        59643904 245190655 185546752 88.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sda4       245190656 250068991   4878336  2.3G  0 Empty
```

On the first system where I retrieve the data, the types are listed as a list with decimal value, name, UUID.
On the new system, the list of known partition types hex values. (Linux 83, swap 82, uefi EF...).
Types can be seen running:

> $ fdisk /dev/sda

PC1:

```
Command (m for help): l

00 Empty            24 NEC DOS          81 Minix / old Lin  bf Solaris
01 FAT12            27 Hidden NTFS Win  82 Linux swap / So  c1 DRDOS/sec (FAT-
02 XENIX root       39 Plan 9           83 Linux            c4 DRDOS/sec (FAT-
03 XENIX usr        3c PartitionMagic   84 OS/2 hidden or   c6 DRDOS/sec (FAT-
...
```

PC2:

```
Command (m for help): l
  1 EFI System                     C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  2 MBR partition scheme           024DEE41-33E7-11D3-9D69-0008C781F39F
  3 Intel Fast Flash               D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593
  4 BIOS boot                      21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
  5 Sony boot partition            F4019732-066E-4E12-8273-346C5641494F
  6 Lenovo boot partition          BFBFAFE7-A34F-448A-9A5B-6213EB736C22
  7 PowerPC PReP boot              9E1A2D38-C612-4316-AA26-8B49521E5A8B
  ...
```

Comment: Observation: On the new system `fdisk -l` shows you a dos partition table. GUIDs belong to GUID partition table (GPT).

Comment: Probably the GPT header is missing.

Comment: I don't know `sfdisk` *at all*, but after a quick scan of `man 8 sfdisk` i *suspect* you need `--label gpt` when importing your `.tbl`. What if you use `sfdisk --label gpt /dev/sda < "table-file.tbl" --no-reread`?

Answer (score 0):

Different label types use different partition types values. "dos" != "gpt"

Setting the --label as suggested in comments solved the issue:

> sfdisk --label gpt /dev/sda < "table-file.tbl" --no-reread